# Destructor and thread safety

Tags: c++, synchronization, destructor

I want to create a thread safe class containing a method to insert elements into a list.
When one of the threads destroys an instance, I want the messages in the list to be processed, while preventing other threads to insert other messages.

The idea is the following:

```
MyClass{
   ...
   public:
      ...
      void send(string s){
          lock_guard<mutex> lock(m); 
          my_list.push_back(s);
      }
      ~MyClass(){
          lock_guard<mutex> lock(m); 
          for(string s:my_list)
              process(s);
      }
}
```

Is the synchronization correct?

For the method `send` I added the lock so that multiple threads can call it in a safe way.

As for what concerns the destructor, is there a possibility that a thread will call `send` between the lock release and the actual destruction of the instance? ie. is the `for` (and the following `lock_guard` destruction) the last instruction that will be executed before the actual destruction, or a race condition is possible once the destructor is executed?

Comment: If you are in the destructor, you should be able to assume nobody has any kind of pointer or reference to `this` that they can use, otherwise they would be using a dangling pointer/reference. Nothing special happens at the end of the destructor that would prevent someone from calling `send`. In other words, if there is a chance `send` might be called, you shouldn't be in the destructor yet.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That might be the goal of the message: removing reference to *self* in other classes (unsubscribe observer, ...).

Comment: @Jarod42 Then there is a design problem. The object would be getting destroyed while one of it's member functions might be running.

Comment: The problem is that your mutex doesn't prevent anyone from *calling* send, it only prevents the function body from moving beyond the first line. Eventually, that mutex will unlock and the execution will continue rather or not there is still a `this`. You would have to abort the function call somehow, but without relying on `this` in any way. And you would have to do the same with every other member function that might be called.

Comment: "for(string s:my_list)"
Should be:
"for(string &s: my_list)"
so it doesn't make useless copies.

Answer (score 1):

You might split your class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void send(const std::string& s){
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m); 
        my_list.push_back(s);
    }

    void process_all_messages()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
        for (const string& s : my_list)
            process(s);
        //my_list.clear();
    }

    void process(const std::string& s);

// ... mutex, list, ...
};
```

And have a wrapper on it

```
class MyClassPerTHread
{
public:
    explicit MyClassPerTHread(std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    ~MyClassPerTHread(){ ptr->process_all_messages(); }

    // MyClassPerTHread(const MyClassPerTHread&);
    // MyClassPerTHread(MyClassPerTHread&&);
    // MyClassPerTHread& operator=(const MyClassPerTHread&);
    // MyClassPerTHread& operator=(MyClassPerTHread&&);

    void send(const std::string& s) { ptr->send(s); };
private:
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr;
};
```

So in `main`, you create an instance of `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`.
you pass it to each thread which wrap it in `MyClassPerTHread`.

When `MyClassPerTHread` is destroyed, You process the messages as expected.

You might want to adapt `MyClassPerTHread` for move/copy though.

Comment: You could simplify this by having clients operate on a std::shared_ptr<MyClass> directly. This is idiomatic, and has all the advantages that MyClassPerThread has.

Comment: shared_ptr<MyClass> also has the advantage of less contention due to fewer calls to process_all_messages().

Comment: @ech: As I understand, OP wants a callback each time the ref counter of `shared_ptr<MyClass>` would decrease, so the proposed split.

Comment: interesting – yeah, if you wanted that behavior then the -perthread class makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good intuition here; the `lock_guard` in the destructor isn't doing any good at all.

Here's why:
The way this is written, any calls to `send()` must be done before `~MyClass()`'s lock_guard is created – otherwise the message won't get processed and `send()` could very well be using m and my_list after their destruction is complete, leading to undefined behavior. Callers of `send()` have no way to make sure this happens other than just making sure all calls to `send()` are done before `~MyClass()` even starts.

This is OK. Most classes have (or should have) a requirement that clients serialize destruction. That is, clients must make sure all callers to `send()` are done *before* `~MyClass()` is invoked. In fact, all standard library classes have this requirement, unless otherwise documented. Some classes deliberately don't require this; that's fine, but somewhat exotic.

This really isn't terribly hard for clients to do, fortunately; they can just use a shared_ptr or something, as suggested by Jarod42.

tl;dr:

> is there a possibility that a thread will call send between the lock release and the actual destruction of the instance?

Yes! Document that it is a client error if they do this and get rid of the lock in the destructor.